# How to get "days ago, hours ago" time format in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone

I want to get the time/date format like hours ago,days ago in iOS.But i am getting the wrong data. For example if time is:

```
2015-10-21 03:43:20
```

then according to below code it show me 6 hours ago. I am using Now() function in php to save the time/date so how can i display exact time for diffrent countries?

```
+(NSString*)HourCalculation:(NSString*)PostDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:gmt];
    NSDate *ExpDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:PostDate];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:ExpDate toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSString *time;
    if(components.year!=0)
    {
        if(components.year==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld year",(long)components.year];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld years",(long)components.year];
        }
    }
    else if(components.month!=0)
    {
        if(components.month==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld month",(long)components.month];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld months",(long)components.month];
        }
    }
    else if(components.week!=0)
    {
        if(components.week==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld week",(long)components.week];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld weeks",(long)components.week];
        }
    }
    else if(components.day!=0)
    {
        if(components.day==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld day",(long)components.day];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld days",(long)components.day];
        }
    }
    else if(components.hour!=0)
    {
        if(components.hour==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld hour",(long)components.hour];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld hours",(long)components.hour];
        }
    }
    else if(components.minute!=0)
    {
        if(components.minute==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld min",(long)components.minute];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld mins",(long)components.minute];
        }
    }
    else if(components.second>=0)
    {
        if(components.second==0)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 sec"];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld secs",(long)components.second];
        }
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ago",time];
}
```

Comment: Have you searched?  I'm certain this has been asked before.

Answer (score 9):

A few observations:

1. First, you can greatly simplify this code if you use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`, e.g.

   ```
   NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
   formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull;
   formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
   NSString *elapsed = [formatter stringFromDate:someDate toDate:[NSDate date]];
   ```

   That generates a string that represents the time between two `NSDate` objects, like so:

   > 5 years, 9 months, 20 days, 3 hours, 48 minutes, 56 seconds

   Or you can specify the maximum unit count, and it will only show the *n* largest ones. For example:

   ```
   formatter.maximumUnitCount = 2;
   ```

   And that will generate:

   > 5 years, 10 months
2. Note the use of constants such as `NSCalendarUnitYear` not `NSYearCalendarUnit`.
3. If the elapsed time is off, the most common situation is the incorrect timezone in the time string. The simplest way to avoid these sorts of issues is to make sure that the string you receive from the server is either in a known timezone (e.g. GMT) or that the time string includes the timezone. Often we'll use ISO 8601/RFC 3339 date formats in web services and adjust our date formatter accordingly (see Apple [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html), which discusses some subtle issues there).

Answer (score -2):

you can download NSDate+NVTimeAgo class from github with the following link,,
https://github.com/nikilster/NSDate-Time-Ago
I sure its work for you.